# Nested loops in chart templates

Tags: kubernetes, go-templates, kubernetes-helm

I'm having trouble rendering a template for a Helm Chart that needs to have easily expandable amounts of nodes and replicas. I get the below error message. What's odd is I do not get the below error message if I remove the inner loop to not nest loops. I'm completely new to go, but this seems valid. I'm at a loss.

Error:

```
$ helm install . --dry-run --debug
Error: render error in "app-on-k8s/templates/configmap_configd.yaml": template: app-on-k8s/templates/configmap_configd.yaml:18:77: executing "app-on-k8s/templates/configmap_configd.yaml" at <.Values.nodeCount>: can't evaluate field Values in type int
```

This is the relevant section from my values.yaml file:

```
# number of nodes / shards
nodeCount: 5
replicaCount: 3
```

And the relevant section from my template file:

```
    <default>
        {{range $i, $e := until (atoi (printf "%d" (int64 .Values.nodeCount))) }}
                <node>
                {{range $j, $k := until (atoi (printf "%d" (int64 .Values.replicaCount))) }}   #line 18
                    <replica>
                        <host>{{ $.Release.Name }}-{{$j}}</host>
                        <port>{{ $.Values.service.rpc_port }}</port>
                    </replica>
                {{end}}    
                </node>
        {{end}}
    </default>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is, when you are using `.Values.replicaCount` in the second loop,`.` scope has been changed and now pointing at `.Values.nodeCount`. So `.Values.replicaCount` now pointing to `.Values.nodeCount.Values.replicaCount`. Since, there is no such field in values.yaml file you are getting this error.

Use `$.Values.replicaCount` instead of `.Values.replicaCount` in second loop.

Ref: [helm.sh](https://docs.helm.sh/chart_template_guide/#looping-with-the-range-action)